# How to measure security level of digital signature?

Tags: digital-signature, integrity

I want to measure the guarantee of integrity of a digital signature.

I use RSA with a 4096 bit key, and SHA 256, and a passphrase.  The level of security is going to depend on these three factors, yeah?

How do I measure how safe the digital signature is?

Comment: How securely the private key is stored is one of the most significant indicators of the signature's integrity.

Comment: You might be interested in something like the [SOGIS Agreed Cryptographic Mechanisms](https://www.sogis.eu/uk/supporting_doc_en.html). From their explanation why they consider which security algorithms strong enough, you can get an idea of the parameters involved.

Comment: @mkl  Good!  I'll check it out.